# Exponential relationship issue

Tags: exponential-function

I read this relation and I am not sure why this is true, is it I can't see why it would be?

$$(e^{ -i\pi/2})^{ -ix}\approx ie^{-\pi x/2} $$ I get that $e^{i\pi/2}=-i$, but I can't see why this relation would be true.

Comment: There must be an error. The quantity on the left is equal to $e^{-\pi x/2}$ exactly; the extra $i$ is not correct.

Comment: I don't think the relation is true.  The expression on the left is $(-i)^{-ix}$.  There is no universal convention for raising $-i$ to a non-integer power, which is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful working with complex exponentials because of problems with multivalued logarithms.  The exponential $a^b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$  is usually defined in terms of the multivalued logarithm as $e^{b \log a}$.

*As a multivalued expression*, we have
\begin{align*}
(e^{-i \pi/2 })^{-ix} &= e^{-ix \log (e^{-i \pi/2 })} \\
&= e^{-ix (-i\pi/2 + 2\pi i k) } && (k \text{ an integer; } k = 0 \text{ for principle log})\\
&= e^{-x\pi/2 + 2\pi x k} \\
&= e^{2\pi k x}e^{-x\pi/2}
\end{align*}

Therefore, for your statement to be true (in the sense that for one branch it works) we would have to have
\begin{align*}
e^{2\pi k x}e^{-x\pi/2} &= i e^{-x\pi/2} \\
\iff e^{2\pi k x} &= i \\
\iff e^{2\pi k x} &= e^{i \pi / 2} \\
\iff 2 \pi k x &\equiv i \pi / 2 \pmod {2\pi i}
\end{align*}

For this to be true, $x$ must be purely imaginary.  Let $x = i(m + r)$ where $m$ is an integer and $0 \le r < 1$ real.
\begin{align*}
2 \pi k (i(m + r)) &\equiv i \pi / 2 \pmod {2\pi i} \\
\iff 2 \pi i m k + 2 \pi i k r &\equiv i \pi / 2 \pmod {2\pi i} \\
\iff mk + kr &\equiv 1 / 4 \pmod {1} \\
\iff kr &\equiv 1 / 4 \pmod {1}
\end{align*}

In summary: the only time your statement could actually be sort of true is when $x$ is purely imaginary, and the fractional part of the imaginary part of $x$ (i.e. $r$ above) multiplied by some integer $k$ has a fractional part of $1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

Given $z$, $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$, $z\neq 0$

$$z^{\omega}=e^{\omega Log(z)} $$

where $$Log(z)=log(|z|)+i(arg(z)) $$

Let $ z = e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}},- $ $\omega=-ix$

Then

$$(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}})^{-ix}=e^{-ix(Log(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}}))} $$

$$Log(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}})=log|1|+i(-\frac{\pi}{2})=-i\frac{\pi}{2} $$

so

$$(e^{-i\frac{\pi}{2}})^{-ix}=e^{-ix(-i\frac{\pi}{2})}=e^{-\frac{x\pi}{2}} $$

I'm sorry I don't get the factor $i$

Comment: yeah that is what i get but the factor i is important, mm il have another think

Comment: @user73685 can you give some context? It may be very important

Answer (score -1):

Use basic index laws.

$$
(e^a)^b = e^{ab}
$$
What do you get when you do this?

Comment: This isn't true in general for complex $a$ and $b$ -- not even as a multivalued expression.

Comment: It wasn't a complete answer, and that was for good reason.